# How to pipeline my 2s complement multiplier?

Tags: vhdl

I have designed a 8x8 2s complement multiplier in VHDL and it doesn't seem to fit the needs for my PSD estimator and I think I have to transform it into pipeline. Here you have my multiplier. Can anyone tell me how can I apply the pipeline for my multiplier to run faster?

Regards

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;



entity  mult_secv  is 
  generic(
    Na    : integer := 8;
    Nb    : integer := 8;
    Nbcnt : integer := 4
   );
  port(
    iCLK  : in std_logic;
    iRST    : in std_logic;
    iDV   : in std_logic;

    ia      : in std_logic_vector(Na-1 downto 0);
    ib      : in std_logic_vector(Nb-1 downto 0);

    oDV     : out std_logic;
    oDATA   : out std_logic_vector(Na+Nb-2 downto 0)
    );
end  mult_secv;

architecture produs of mult_secv is

signal  sa, srez : std_logic_vector(Na+Nb-2 downto 0);
signal  sb : std_logic_vector(Nb-1 downto 0);
signal scnt    : std_logic_vector(Nbcnt-1 downto 0);
signal scntmax : std_logic_vector(Nbcnt-1 downto 0) := "0111";


begin

process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    sa <= (others => '0');      
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    if iDV='1' then
      sa <= (Na+Nb-2 downto Na => ia(Na-1))  & ia; 
    else
      sa <= sa(Na+Nb-3 downto 0) & '0'; 
    end if;
  end if;
end process;


process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    sb <= (others => '0');      
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    if iDV='1' then
      sb <= ib;
    else
      sb <= '0' & sb(Nb-1 downto 1);
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    srez <= (others => '0');        
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    if iDV='1' then
       srez <= (others => '0');
      if ib(Nb-1)='1' then
        srez <= not (ia & (Nb-2 downto 0 => '0')) + '1';
      else
        srez <= (others => '0');
      end if;
    elsif sb(0)='1' then        
      srez <= srez+sa;
    else    
      srez <= srez;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    scnt <= (others =>'0');
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    if iDV='1' then
      scnt <= (Nbcnt-1 downto 1 => '0') & '1';
    elsif scnt=scntmax then
      scnt <= (others  => '0');
    else 
      scnt <= scnt +'1';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;


oDATA <= srez;


process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    oDV <= '0';
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    if scnt=scntmax then
      oDV <= '1';
    else
      oDV <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;


end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Synthesis tools these days will generate this all for you.  It's literally as simple as this:

```
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;



entity  mult_secv  is 
  generic(
    Na    : integer := 8;
    Nb    : integer := 8;
    Nbcnt : integer := 4
   );
  port(
    iCLK  : in std_logic;
    iRST    : in std_logic;
    iDV   : in std_logic;

    ia      : in std_logic_vector(Na-1 downto 0);
    ib      : in std_logic_vector(Nb-1 downto 0);

    oDV     : out std_logic;
    oDATA   : out std_logic_vector(Na+Nb-2 downto 0)
    );
end  mult_secv;

architecture produs of mult_secv is

begin

process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    oDV   <= '0';
    oDATA <= (others => '0');      
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    if iDV='1' then
      oDV   <= '1';
      oDATA <= ia*ib;
    else
      oDV   <= '0';
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: Synthesis tools will generate a pipelined multiplier? How many pipeline stages, i.e. what latency?

Comment: Actually you haven't provided a use clause making a multiplying operator visible with a signature of [std_logic_vector,std_logic_vector return std_logic_vector].

Comment: This also isn't a signed multiplier.

Comment: Thanks. But I need an ideea on how to implement MY multiplier in pipeline, I need it 'old-school', as I need to improve the execution time of my multiplier(ideas, stages, anything)

Comment: What do you mean by pading one of the operands?

Comment: @fru1tbat Yes. They can synthesize pipelined multipliers: 1) force implementation of a distributed multiplier. 2) Add chains of flip-flops to the product output and enable register retiming/balancing. The results are serviceable but not as optimal as a hand tuned circuit.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Russell's answer was ambiguous to me though. It appeared to suggest, given the question, that what he wrote would result in a pipelined multiplier. Adding register chains and retiming is different.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this (not tested but the idea is here). There are still 8 clock cycles to calculate but the multiplier is now pipelined.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity  mult_secv  is 
  generic(
    Na    : integer := 8;
    Nb    : integer := 8;
    Nbcnt : integer := 4
   );
  port(
    iCLK  : in std_logic;
    iRST    : in std_logic;
    iDV   : in std_logic;

    ia      : in std_logic_vector(Na-1 downto 0);
    ib      : in std_logic_vector(Nb-1 downto 0);

    oDV     : out std_logic;
    oDATA   : out std_logic_vector(Na+Nb-2 downto 0)
    );
end  mult_secv;

architecture produs of mult_secv is

-- 8 stage array
signal  sa, srez : array (1 to 8) of std_logic_vector(Na+Nb-2 downto 0);
signal  sb : array (1 to 8) of std_logic_vector(Nb-1 downto 0);
signal  dv : array (1 to 8) of std_logic;

constant scntmax : integer := 8;


begin

-- for each pipeline stage
for scnt in 1 to scntmax generate

process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    sa <= (others => (others => '0'));
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    -- first stage
    if (scnt = 1) then
      sa(scnt) <= (Na+Nb-2 downto Na => ia(Na-1))  & ia; 
    -- other stages
    else
      sa(scnt) <= sa(scnt-1)(Na+Nb-3 downto 0) & '0'; 
    end if;
  end if;
end process;


process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    sb <= (others => (others => '0'));   
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    if (scnt = 1) then
      sb(scnt) <= ib;
    else
      sb(scnt) <= '0' & sb(scnt-1)(Nb-1 downto 1);
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    srez <= (others => (others => '0'));  
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    if (scnt = 1) then
      if ib(Nb-1)='1' then
        srez(scnt) <= not (ia & (Nb-2 downto 0 => '0')) + '1';
      else
        srez(scnt) <= (others => '0');
      end if;
    elsif sb(scnt-1)(0)='1' then        
      srez(scnt) <= srez(scnt-1)+sa(scnt-1);
    else    
      srez(scnt) <= srez(scnt-1);
    end if;
  end if;
end process;    

process(iCLK,iRST)
begin
  if iRST='1' then
    dv <= (others => '0');
  elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
    if (scnt = 1) then
      dv(scnt) <= iDV;
    else
      dv(scnt) <= dv(scnt-1);
    end if;
  end if;
end process;

end generate;

oDATA <= srez(scntmax);
oDv <= dv(scntmax);

end;
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand the idea with the array, but it must be slightly diffrent, I think, because it seems to be a conflict here `sa(scnt) <= (Na+Nb-2 downto Na => ia(Na-1))  & ia;` because `sa` is array type and `ia` is a signal. Can anyone tell me how can I replace array in a such way that my conflict doesn't exist?

Comment: try this : `sa(scnt) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(ia),Na+Nb-2));`The resize function will duplicate the sign bit on upper bits automatically. sa(cnt) is an std_logic_vector.

Comment: it's okay. I think the problem was to put a label for the generate for. but it doesn't work when I try to multiply 11101111 with  11111101 , for example

Comment: I've set it like in the entity, ia is 11101111 and ib is 11111101.In the begining i let it run 20 ns on reset, then ia and ib takes those values. Why it doesn't work? in my original multiplier, the multiplication can be made