# I am trying to pipeline a 8x8 2s complement multiplier and I don't know why it doesn't work

Tags: vhdl

I am curently working on a project and I am trying to pipeline a multiplier for my psd estimator and I've got some help and the pipeline modification is here. It seems that it's made but i don't know what is not working. Can anyone help? If necessary, I will post the original one too.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


    entity  mult_secv  is 
      generic(
        Na    : integer := 8;
        Nb    : integer := 8;
        Nscnt : integer := 4
       );
      port(
        iCLK  : in std_logic;
        iRST    : in std_logic;
        iDV   : in std_logic;

        ia      : in std_logic_vector(Na-1 downto 0);
        ib      : in std_logic_vector(Nb-1 downto 0);

        oDV     : out std_logic;
        oDATA   : out std_logic_vector(Na+Nb-2 downto 0)
        );
    end  mult_secv;

    architecture produs of mult_secv is
      type my_array1 is array(1 to 8)of std_logic_vector(Na+Nb-2 downto 0);
      type my_array2 is array(1 to 8) of std_logic_vector(Nb-1 downto 0);
      type my_array3 is  array(1 to 8) of std_logic;
    --8 stagii pentru a se calcula tot produsul
      signal sa, srez : my_array1;   
      signal sb : my_array2;
      signal dv : my_array3;
      constant scntmax : integer:=8 ;

    begin
      -- for each pipeline stage
    generarestagii : for scnt in 1 to scntmax generate ---> CAUTA SINTAXA PENTRU GENERARE DE COMPONENTE IDENTICE

    process(iCLK,iRST)
    begin
      if iRST= '1' then
        sa <= (others => (others => '0'));
      elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
        -- first stage
        if (scnt = 1) then
          sa(scnt) <= (Na+Nb-2 downto Na => ia(Na-1))  & ia; ---se bordeaza cu bitul de semn daca e negativ
          --sa(scnt) <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(ia),Na+Nb-2));
        -- other stages
        else
          sa(scnt) <= sa(scnt-1)(Na+Nb-3 downto 0) & '0';  --altfel se shifteaza sa
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;


    process(iCLK,iRST)
    begin
      if iRST='1' then
        sb <= (others => (others => '0'));   
      elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
        if (scnt = 1) then
          sb(scnt) <= ib;
        else
          sb(scnt) <= '0' & sb(scnt-1)(Nb-1 downto 1); --se shifteaza sb
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;

    process(iCLK,iRST)
    begin
      if iRST='1' then
        srez <= (others => (others => '0'));  
      elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
        if (scnt = 1) then
          if ib(Nb-1)='1' then
       srez(scnt) <= not (ia & (Nb-2 downto 0 => '0')) + '1'; --daca este negativ
          else
            srez(scnt) <= (others => '0'); --in primul stadiu
          end if;
        elsif sb(scnt-1)(0)='1' then        
          srez(scnt) <= srez(scnt-1)+sa(scnt-1);
        else    
          srez(scnt) <= srez(scnt-1);
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;    

    process(iCLK,iRST)
    begin
      if iRST='1' then
        dv <= (others => '0');
      elsif rising_edge(iCLK) then
        if (scnt = 1) then
          dv(scnt) <= iDV;
        else
          dv(scnt) <= dv(scnt-1);
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;

    end generate generarestagii;

    oDATA <= srez(scntmax);
    oDv <= dv(scntmax);

    end;
```

Comment: Do you get an error, or does it compile ok, but the algorithm doesn't work? Can you characterize the problem better (error messages, test results, etc.)?

Comment: The program compiles okay, but when I try to simmulate the program for 11101111 and 11111101, it doesn't work.(Where is the problem?) Note that in my first model of non-pipelined multiplier, the simmulation runs perfect for these numbers. Here is the code for my original one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379811/how-to-pipeline-my-2s-complement-multiplier

Comment: I need an extra opinion about this code because it is good for me but i don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: And other values work correctly? Or do all values fail? And what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Returns values that are wrong? Returns 'X', maybe?

Comment: No, none of the values work. the multiplication doesn't start. Here are my simmulations force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/irst 1 0
force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/idv 0 0
force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/ia 00000000 0
force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/ib 00000000 0


run 13 ns

force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/irst 0 0
force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/ia 11101111 0
force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/ib 11111101 0
force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/idv 1 0


run 10 ns
force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/ia 00000000 0
force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/ib 00000000 0
force -freeze sim:/mult_secv/idv 0 0

run 100 ns

Answer (score 1):

There are several improvements that can be made to your code, but the only real problem is `sa <= (others => (others => '0'));` (and similar) in your reset code for all your processes. You're inside a generate loop, and when it gets unrolled, you end up with each process replicated *n* times, so you've created multiple drivers on the same signals. You should change it to `sa(scnt) <= (others => '0')` (and similar).

Comment: Thanks, that resolved one of the problems. Now, when I run the simmulation, sa and sb are shifted correctly but srez is not storring the result.

Comment: Did you make the same correction to `srez` (and `dv`)? What is `srez` storing instead?

Comment: Great! I've made it work. Thank you! Furthermore, I have yet another question. Is this code really pipeline?(It respects the pipeline design?)

Comment: Oh, wait! For negative numbers it doesn't work(for example for 3 times -7)

Comment: Now it does. Thank you a lot! Although it works, is it pipeline?